# os.system(...) call to a function that shares files does not quit on one core (mpi4py)

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multithreading, os.system, mpi4py

**Background** I am running a python program in parallel using mpi4py.

I distribute files on each core, so that each core has 1 file (there are 2 cores); this is just a test scenario.

Each core now runs a program "prog.exe" which takes say 5 minutes to complete. I use os.system(...) and right after that call I use a Barrier() (in case core i finishes before core j).

I have tested some simple os.system(...) calls (such as simply echoing something) and it works fine.

But, prog.exe is a program that needs to read in a file on disk. This file is the same across cores. So when os.system(...) is called prog.exe goes and reads the file, but it does so for both cores.

**Problem**
What happens is that one core finishes (it seems to be always the root in what I have tested) and the other does not.

**Hypothesis** One core opens the file (by getting to it first) and then does some parsing. Then, the other core gets to the file but woops, it's already open so can't do  that.

**Potential solution** So, the solution seems to be to let each core copy the file to its own folder. But then, can cores in parallel copy a file or is there a similar lock being put on the file during copying?

**Questions for the community**

1. Is my hypothesis correct? The program crashes because of a lock on the file?
2. In more general terms, how do you deal with this scenario where cores share the loading of same data files (seems to be a common thing)? Do each core copy the file? Is that possible considering locks etc.?

**Further reflections**
If reading the same file is not an issue, then the problem must exist in my prog.exe, but in that case, could it please be confirmed that reading the same file is OK.

Thanks

Comment: Just an update: After further study of this I am pretty convinced that multiple cores _can_ read the same file. The issue is most likely with prog.exe